# Issue upgrading ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS server

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I have been trying to upgrading my Ubuntu server from the following :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have updated the system

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Get:1 https://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 https://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 https://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:4 https://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Get:5 https://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]
Hit:6 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial InRelease
Get:7 https://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Get:8 https://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8,344 B]

Fetched 29.9 MB in 7s (4,183 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the output of `grep Prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` ?

Comment: Hi output : Prompt=lts
I have tried it with normal as well

Answer (score 0):

#### The regualr way to upgrade

To upgrade from `lts` to `lts`, edit your `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` with the following line:

```
Prompt=lts
```

Then run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

See: [Upgrade policy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades#Upgrade_policy)

#### The [Debian way of upgrading](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades#The_Debian_way_of_upgrading):

```
sudo sed -i.ORIG 's/xenial/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d.ORIG/
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

[Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 17.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades#The_Debian_way_of_upgrading)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the assist.

Problem was in :

/etc/update-manager/meta-release    # There was a couple lines for some monitoring software removed them and saved and worked perfectly :)

command that assisted , cant remember where i saw it but thank you

export DEBUG_UPDATE_MANGER=true

Hope this helps anyone else that has this problem